# Objects showing in iPhone Sim but not iPad sim

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ipad

Full disclosure: I'm very new to iOS development.

Using Xcode Version 7.2.1, Swift programming language, targeting 9.0

I have a very simple app. Universal. When running in simulator mode it works fine for any iphone chosen in the simulator. Everything shows up where it's supposed to etc.

When running it in iPad simulators, any of them, the only thing showing up is the navigation bar. All objects that are supposed to show up on the screen, are gone.

When debugging, the objects seem to get created alright.
Maybe there's something to be done in AppDelegate?

As I imagine this is a really noob problem I again like to emphasise that I'm grateful for any suggestions you may have.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979387/view-not-showing-up-in-ipad-only-in-iphone

Comment: check you constraints and size class on which it was applied

Comment: put some screenshot of ipad storyborad, or Main,storyboard.  also Log the objects, and show code.

Comment: @dan thanks. yes, this was the problem. Thanks. I have no idea what to do with this question since it's technically a duplicate of the one you linked to.